# How to draw these cartesian planes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I should draw these cartesian planes with straight lines, but I have problems in drawing the axes because they have different scales and therefore I do not know how to draw the straight lines. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

%   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
%   %\usepackage{mathpple}
%   %\usepackage{palatino}
%   
%   \usepackage{lxfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={font=\Large}] 
    \npaddplus
    \tkzInit[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=5,ymax=5]
    \tkzGrid % moved before \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzAxeX[
       label=\hspace{4mm}\Large $\\ time [min]  $,
       very thick, % increase width of axes lines
       label options={font=\large}, % increase font size 
       orig=false % don't print zeros
    ]
    \tkzAxeY[
       label=\raisebox{4mm}{\Large $price \$ $},
       very thick, % increase width of axes lines
       label options={font=\large,}, % increase font size 
       orig=false % don't print zeros
    ]
    \node [below right=3pt,fill=white,font=\large] {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tkz-euclide` might not be invented for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `pgfplots` is better suited for the job. Here's something to get you started

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

% first plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain = 0 : 250,
      xmin = 0, xmax = 250,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 350,
      xlabel = {time [min]},
      ylabel = {cost [\$]},
      axis lines = left,
      grid,
      grid style = {line width = 1pt, draw = gray!10},
    ]
  %\addplot[mark=*,blue] coordinates {(2,2) (5,8) (7,16)};
  \addplot[red, thick, path fading = east] {50 + \x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


% second plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin = 0, xmax = 7,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 20,
      xlabel = {time [min]},
      ylabel = {cost [\$]},
      axis lines = left,
      grid,
      grid style = {line width = 1pt, draw = gray!10},
    ]
  \addplot[mark = *, red] coordinates {
    (1, 2.9)
    (2, 5.7)
    (3, 8.6)
    (4, 11.4)
    (5, 14.3)
    (6, 17.1)
    (7, 20.0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! How can I cancel the zero from y-axis? @caverac

Comment: @ryuk Change the value of `ymin`

Comment: how to change the interval of y axis values? form 0,100,200 to 0,50,100,150,200? thanks a lot!

Comment: @ryuk Use `ytick={0, 50, 100, 150, 200}`

Comment: sorry but I can not understand. What can I do to configure the x-axis scale? number like 0,20,40,60 ...and so on, or 0,50,100,150,200... and so on? In my code where do I have to add the changes? @caverac

Comment: @ryuk `\begin{axis}[put here all your options]`, you can add there configurations for the color, number of ticks, positions, ranges, .... In particular you just need to add `\begin{axis}[ytick={0, 50, 100, 150, 200}, ...]`

Comment: thank you so much! now it works! last question...how can i modify the fading of the red line of the first graph?

Comment: @ryuk Sorry about that one :) Replace  `\addplot[red, thick, path fading = east] {50 + \x};` by `\addplot[red, thick] {50 + \x};`

Comment: thanks ;) for example how can I modify the code if i would like to start the fading from the point (200,250) to the end of the line? thank you so much ;)